# CommonJS - How can I combine jquery and a jquery-plugin into the $ namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-plugins, commonjs

What I'm trying to do is adapt my jQuery-plugin to work with jQuery on Node.js.

From what I understand, CommonJS in it's most basic form requires a library to be wrapped in a closure, and that closure should be made available as a parameter of an 'exports' parameter. That way, the code is neatly contained in its own namespace (via a named variable) and doesn't pollute the global namespace.

jQuery itself should fall under the '$' namespace.

**Ala:**

```
var $ = require(jquery);
```

But my plugin should also fit under the '$' namespace.

**Plugin code:**

```
(function( $ ) {
  // plugin code goes here
})(jquery);

exports.jquery = jquery // will this work?
```

**Ex:**

```
var $ = require(jquery);
$ = require(jquery-csv.js); // will this work?
```

To work in the browser, everything is setup to be callable from the '$' namespace even though my modules are setup as a sub-namespace of '$' (ie '$.csv').

Is there a standard way to do multiple requires on a single namespace? If not, there a viable alternative (ex doing a shallow copy on the plugin code)?

*Note: The anonymous function wrapper follows the [standard jquery guidelines](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).*

*Note: This fix will be applied to the [jquery-csv](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) plugin.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should require jQuery *inside* your plugin:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
```

This is also the technique in [UMD (Universal Module Definition)](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), a standard for both CommonJS and AMD.

Also see the [example for a jQuery plugin with UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/jqueryPluginCommonjs.js)

Comment: And if jquery isn't actually used? I'm trying to cover both use cases so it'll bind to $ whether or not jquery is actually present.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I can think of doing something like this would be doing something like the following:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
require("jquery-csv")($);
```

That also means you can just do something like this:

```
module.exports = exports = function (jquery) {
    //You modify the jquery object here.
};
```

Modification of the $ object should be done in accordance to jQuery plugins recommendations. I will believe you are already aware of them for what you said.

I'm sure someone will come up with a smarter way :) but this should work for now. You could also just return a modified jquery object and then assign it to the $ object on the scope in which you originally included the module.

Comment: I just finished setting up my node env and the solution was even simpler than that. You don't need to add an exports call to the plugin because it's mutating an existing namespace. By calling require without an assignment, it acts the same as importing using a <script> tag.

Comment: @mamsaac could you please provide a little update on exactly how you are wrapping the plugin, is the second $ really necessary

Answer (score 0):

**The answer turned out to be simpler than I thought...**

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
require('./jquery.csv.js');
```

Calling 'require' without assigning it to a variable/namespace acts the same as a script import (ie it can manipulate objects that exist in the global namespace).

The first line takes care of properly initializing jquery. Once that's done, jquery-csv can modify the existing '$' namespace the same way it does in the browser.

The second assignment 'jQuery' is necessary because that's where jquery-csv grabs the reference to the 'jquery' instance. This could probably be shortened to only assign to '$' but 'jQuery' is the value that the plugin guidelines specify for referencing the library.

Comment: Beware of `var a = b = c = d;`: it leaks `b` and `c` into the global!

Comment: Damn JS quirks. So multiple var assignment statements would prevent polluting the global namespace?

Comment: @joeytwiddle I think the above answer works because you need jQuery to be a global object, just as it would be in the browser when called via script tags (eg window.jQuery).

Comment: @EvanPlaice yes they would. Sorry for late reply!

Comment: @MCTaylor17 Good theory. If the intention *really is* to pollute the global, then it is idiomatic to make that intention explicitly clear: `global.jQuery = $;` or `window.jQuery = $;` to avoid later developers (like ourselves) from having to speculate about the original developer's intent.